# How to show the custom error message without stack trace using suitescript 2.0 in netsuite

Tags: javascript, error-handling, netsuite, suitescript

I want to show the custom error message with out stack trace to user using "suitescript 2.0"version. In workflow the custom error message is showing without stack trace but in Suite Script the "ERROR MESSAGE " is showing with the stack trace.

**ERROR WITH STACK TRACE:**
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"MISSING_CONTRACT_LINE","message":"Please enter atleast one Contract Line item to save a contract.","stack":["createError(N/error)","beforeSubmit(SuiteScripts/Ex_UE_Contract_2.0.js:117)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"MISSING_CONTRACT_LINE","message":"Please enter atleast one Contract Line item to save a contract."},"id":""}

**I want to show the custom error message without stack trace like this:
"name":"MISSING_CONTRACT_LINE","message":"Please enter atleast one Contract Line item to save a contract."**

**my Code:**

```
     throw error.create({
         name: 'MISSING_CONTRACT_LINE',
         message: 'Please enter atleast one Contract Line item to save a contract.'
     });
```

is there any possible way to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: There's currently a lengthy discussion about this going on in the NetSuite User Group forum as well; I haven't seen any other recommended solution there either. https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/suitescript-2-0-custom-code/413212-throwing-errors-in-suitescript-2-0-outputs-unfriendly-json

Comment: Where you able to find any other solutions to this problem? The selected answer below doesn't appear to work.

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294326/user-friendly-error-message-from-user-event-script-suitescript-2-0/50282012?noredirect=1#comment87580972_50282012

Comment: See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294326/user-friendly-error-message-from-user-event-script-suitescript-2-0/50282012?noredirect=1#comment87580972_50282012) answered on another thread.

Comment: You have to remember error is returning the class `Error` so `stack` will always be a part if it one way or another. If you are not in the `USER_EVENT` type you can use the `N/error` module and clear the `stack` property after its object is created then throw it. But your best bet is to just `log.error` it and then create your own error object without the `N/error` module and return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default implementation of N/error's SuiteScriptError#toString() method is to call JSON.stringify(this), however, the method could overridden per instance to handle cases where the raw error message is intended to be displayed to users via throwing the error out of the script. For example:

```
var err = error.create({name: 'NO_JSON', message: 'This should not be displayed as JSON!'})
err.toString = function(){return err.message};
throw err;
```

Alternatively, it is possible just to throw a String, however, intervening catch blocks would lose the benefit of accessing other properties of the Error, for example, Error#stack or Error#name.

Comment: This solution no longer appears to work. It still writes JSON to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Suite Script Version 2.0:

First define the 'N/error' Module at the top of your function.

```
var errorObj = error.create({
                code: 'Custom Error Message Without JSON',
                message: 'Custom Error Message Without JSON'
            });

            throw errorObj.code + '\n\n' + errorObj.message;
            return false;
```

If you doesn't want the Error CODE to be displayed just use the errorObj.message it will display only the Message.

Answer (score 0):

To save someone the troubles I just went through - as Deepan points out below, define the 'N/error' module and then use the following:

```
var errorObj = error.create({
            code: 'Custom Error Message Without JSON',
            message: 'Custom Error Message Without JSON'
        });

throw errorObj.code + '<br \><br \>' + errorObj.message;
```

The escaped newlines do not work, but treating the thrown message as HTML does indeed insert newlines. I was also able to add newlines in the message parameter in the same manner, which makes things a bit cleaner for my use case:

```
var errorObj = error.create({
        code: 'Custom Error Message Without JSON',
        message: 'Line 1' + '<br \>' + 'Line 2'
    });

throw errorObj.code + errorObj.message;
```

There is also no need for a `return false;` statement after the throw as this is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned answers may fulfil the requirement that it will avoid showing the stack trace on the screen but do remember that there is one disadvantage on it that we cannot avoid the Error notification will be thrown from the netsuite core when an error is triggered on scripts,

```
throw error.create({message:"",code:"",notifyOff:true})
```

this above code will not trigger any mail notifications to users mail by using notifyAll.

```
var errorObj = error.create({
    code: 'Custom Error Message Without JSON',
    message: 'Line 1' + '<br \>' + 'Line 2'
});
throw errorObj.code + errorObj.message;
```

this above way it will going to throw an error notification to the users mail.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah depending on which context you're in. But if I were in the `USER_EVENT` context I would do

```js
let err = {
    name: 'SSS_ERROR',
    message: 'This is an error'
}

// Log the error
log.error(err.name, err.message)

throw `${err.name} - ${err.message}`
```