# Presenting Readable Error from User Event Script in SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0, user-event

I have several user event scripts where if certain kinds of failure occur during the BeforeSubmit event the script needs to be halted and saving of the record prevented. I used this post as a guide to make the errors easier to read some time ago:

[User-friendly error message from user event script (SuiteScript 2.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294326/user-friendly-error-message-from-user-event-script-suitescript-2-0)

However, it looks like with the 2023.1 release they eliminated the ability to have inserted HTML/CSS rendered in the page, and now is instead just directly printed to the output. I assume this was done in tandem with related documented changes like with the injection of HTML/CSS in search results being blocked unless added in with the new HTML formula type.

Is there a different way to accomplish a similar result that works with these system changes? Changing the functionality in the BeforeSubmit event is not feasible, as the work being done has to be done there. If I have to go back to the default display of a thrown error, then I guess that's what will have to be done. Just hoping that I can find a way to get back to displaying readable, meaningful errors when they happen.

Comment: Please provide an example code. But generally one must throw errors, when they want subsequent code not to be executed.